# Printing class variables with a for loop

Tags: python, python-2.7

I realize there are a million other ways to resolve this, so I'm not so much interested in alternative solutions, but more why this doesn't work.

```
class Car(object):

    condition = 'new'

    def __init__(self, model, color, mpg):
        self.model = model
        self.color = color
        self.mpg = mpg

my_car = Car('DeLorean', 'silver', 88)
for x in [condition, model, color, mpg]:
    print my_car.x
```

I'm trying to get it to print my_car.condition, my_car.model, my_car.color, and my_car.mpg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current code is just looking for the `x` attribute on a `Car`, which doesn't exist. You need to do dynamic attribute lookup with `getattr`. First off, though, your list of attributes should contain the appropriate names as strings, so that's:

```
for x in ['condition', 'model', 'color', 'mpg']:
    print(getattr(my_car, x))
```

Comment: The lookup list also needs to be list of strings in this case

Comment: btw: `set(dir(my_car)) - set(dir(type(my_car)))` will give you a set of the names of the attributes of the object which are only existing in the object and not already in the class (so in this case it will be `set(['color', 'mpg', 'model'])`).  Unfortunately, the `"condition"` will not be found this way, and comparing with the attributes of the baseclass clutters the result with internals again: `set(dir(my_car)) - set(dir(type(my_car).__base__))` → `set(['mpg', '__module__', 'color', '__dict__', 'model', '__weakref__', 'condition'])`

Comment: The print is missing : it should be inside the loop `print getattr(my_car, x)`.

Comment: I had actually tried it as strings as well, because that made more sense to me, but it wasn't yielding an output until I used the getattr. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

If that's the order you want all cars to be printed, then you can do this:

```
class Car(object):

    condition = 'new'

    def __init__(self, model, color, mpg):
        self.model = model
        self.color = color
        self.mpg = mpg

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} {} {} {}".format(self.condition, self.model, self.color, self.mpg)

my_car = Car('DeLorean', 'silver', 88)
print my_car
```

Comment: Yeah I realized if I used the __str__ function I wouldn't really have any problems, and that there are a few other ways to do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It does not work because condition, model, color, mpg and my_car.x are not defined.

Comment: Literally, you are right. But you are missing completely the OP's intent.